# Difference between '>=' and '~>=~' in convert like operator with index

Tags: postgresql

I have the following setup.

```
create table test(val text);

create index on test(val text_pattern_ops);
```

I then perform a simple `EXPLAIN SELECT` statement:

```
explain select * from test where val like '1%';
```

...which returns the following:

```
                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=4.22..14.37 rows=7 width=32)
   Filter: (val ~~ '1%'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_val_idx  (cost=0.00..4.22 rows=7 width=0)
         Index Cond: ((val ~>=~ '1'::text) AND (val ~<~ '2'::text))
(4 rows)
```

My second setup is as follows:

```
create table test(val text collate "c");

create index on test(val);
```

...and running the `EXPLAIN SELECT`:

```
explain select * from test where val like '1%';
```

...returns:

```
                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=4.22..14.37 rows=7 width=32)
   Filter: (val ~~ '1%'::text)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_val_idx  (cost=0.00..4.22 rows=7 width=0)
         Index Cond: ((val >= '1'::text) AND (val < '2'::text))
(4 rows)
```

#### Question

Why use `>=` with the column using `collate "c"`?

Answer (score 2):

To handle `LIKE`, you can only use operators that compare strings character by character. This is exactly what `~>=~` does. The normale `>=` operator compares using the database collation, which does not necessarily compare character for character and consequently cannot be used with `LIKE`.

The exception here is the `C` collation: it compares character by character, and PostgreSQL knows that.